# How to convert a univeral date string to local time

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a universal date string and convert it to local time.  For example:
read the string "2002-05-01T15:20:15-08:00" and convert it to the local time equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);    
DateTime utcDate = DateTime.Parse("2002-05-01T15:20:15-08:00", culture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

(untested) Taken from [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/01/Possible_Bug_With_DateTime.Parse.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DateTime.ToLocalTime method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx

Basically something like:
DateTime localTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = DateTimeOffset.Parse(myString).ToLocalTime();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use SOA or BPEL.  I don't know what they are but I heard they can do everything without even really having to think about the problem or even understanding how the architecture works.